# How to move through different records in C#

Tags: c#

I made a form that basically displays information about different vendors from an XML file that I was given. The XML file is retrieved from a class that I created, called VendorsDB.cs. On my form, I have a Previous and Next button that I want to display the next vendor or the previous vendor (Vendor1, Vendor2...) but I have no idea what method to use. I know I have to use a loop but I'm not sure as to how to code the loop. I've just started programming with C# so I'm really lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is a little bit difficult for us to diagnose your problem if we can't see it. Could you show us your code please?

Comment: Look for XDocument and related classes it provides linq over xml.  Its a god send.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing alot of information, but what im seeing is that you need to do some work with XML.

I suggest you look into [Linq To XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) which enabled you to query tags and attributes with query syntax.

A very simple query good look like this:

```
// Load the xml from the specified path
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"LocationOfXml");
// Query the first element with a "MyXmlTag" as name
var someAttribute = xml.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MyXmlTag");
```

The query language is far richer than this simple query. Read up and im sure you'll be able to get it working asap.